# How do I detect fingers with flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to detect the fingers of the person reaching out to the camera with flutter?
example
[image]

Comment: Research about "Android ML" that should give you some direction on how to detect object
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection

Comment: Is there a method with flutter?